# Why does ServiceStack burden the DTOs with routing concerns?

Tags: servicestack

I'm learning ServiceStack, and from reading [this page](https://docs.servicestack.net/your-first-webservice-explained), a couple of things aren't clear to me.

So, considering this DTO pair:

```cs
    [Route("/hello")]
    [Route("/hello/{Name}")]
    public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class HelloResponse
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }
```

And this service:

```cs
    public class MyService : Service
    {
        public object Any(Hello request)
        {
            return new HelloResponse { Result = $"Hello, {request.Name}!" };
        }
    }
```

Why is it the responsibility of `Hello` to specify the return-type using the marker interface `IReturn<HelloResponse>`?

It seems like this could be inferred from the return-type of `MyService` - except that it's conventional to use a return-type of `object`, which also requires type-casts in tests and client-code. Why?

And why are the `Route` attributes applied to the model `Hello`, rather than to the service `MyService`, where the request is actually handled?

It seems like both of these facts are more relevant to the service than to the model.

For one, a person reading the service declaration would more readily find the information pertaining to the service, instead of having to find it in the model.

For another, accepted HTTP methods are implicitly declared by the service via method-naming conventions - so it seems like the facts about service routing/dispatch are sort of scattered between two layers.

From that point of view, I was probably expecting something more along the lines of this:

```cs
    // NON-VALID EXAMPLE

    public class Hello
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class HelloResponse
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyService : Service
    {
        [Route("/hello")]
        [Route("/hello/{Name}")]
        public HelloResponse Any(Hello request)
        {
            return new HelloResponse { Result = $"Hello, {request.Name}!" };
        }
    }
```

What is the reason or the design thinking behind the conventions?

(Please don't take this as merely an attempt at critique - there's a lot of things I enjoy about this framework, and I am genuinely trying to understand the thinking behind these conventions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does ServiceStack burden the DTOs with routing concerns?

Note no routing concern burden is required at all in ServiceStack and all user-defined Routes are optional where all clients are able to call Services utilizing their automatic [pre-defined routes](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#pre-defined-routes).

> Why is it the responsibility of Hello to specify the return-type using the marker interface IReturn?

It provides better typed access for client libraries like the [generic C#/.NET Service Clients](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client) who are able to re-use the existing SericeModel DTOs to enable its optimal typed API without any code-gen, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
var response = client.Get(new Hello { Name = "World" });
```

Or if you're not sharing DTOs it's also useful for [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-add-servicestack-reference) generated clients as well.

The return type on your Service implementation is meaningless in ServiceStack, i.e. has no behavioral difference, and would prevent the same Service implementation from returning the same Response DTO, or decorated with a custom HTTP Response, e.g:

```
public object Any(Hello request)
{
    return new HelloResponse { Result = $"Hello, {request.Name}!" };
    //...
    return new HttpResult(new HelloResponse { Result = $"Hello, {request.Name}!" }) {
      //... custom
    };
}
```

> both return types adhere to the API's `IReturn<HelloResponse>` contract

It's only useful for calling [inter-process Services using the older ResolveService](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway#service-integration-apis) method, but for inter-prcess requests it's recommended to use the [Service Gateway](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway) instead which also utilizes the type `IReturn<T>` interface markers for its Typed APIs.

The routes are not an implementation detail, they're apart of your public Service Contract and should be annotated on your DTOs which are used to define your Service Contract.

```
[Route("/hello")]
[Route("/hello/{Name}")]
public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

Where they're used by the .NET ServiceStack Clients to send Service Client Requests.

```
var response = client.Get(new Hello { Name = "World" });
```

> For another, accepted HTTP methods are implicitly declared by the service via method-naming conventions - so it seems like the facts about service routing/dispatch are sort of scattered between two layers.

Please see docs on [Routing](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing), the Route definition defines which methods the specific route is active on whilst the most appropriate Service implementation is invoked depending on the Request, e.g:

```
public object GetJson(Customers request) => ... // ONLY GET JSON Requests
public object Get(Customers request) => ...     // All other GET Requests
public object Post(Customers request) => ...    // ONLY POST Requests
public object Any(Customers request) => ...     // ALL other Requests
```

> What is the reason or the design thinking behind the conventions?

A lot of these issues is trying to blur the explicit typed Service Contract of your APIs and its concrete implementation, in ServiceStack these are distinct explicit concepts where all the information about your public Service Contract should be maintained in your [implementation-free ServiceModel project](https://docs.servicestack.net/create-your-first-webservice#servicemodel-project).

Please read the [Background Concepts docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/what-is-a-message-based-web-service) to familiarize yourself with ServiceStack's purpose and goals.